# RSS check and instant email when changes

Tags: email, rss, notifications

I am looking to a RSS feed reader or system for Mac OS X that checks every minute or so the feed, and when there are changes it sends me instantly an email. Do you know about something similar?

Comment: On what operating system?

Comment: As an aside: many RSS feeds are cached. So, even checking every minute won't automatically mean you'll see an up-to-date feed. (See, for example, [your own user feed](http://superuser.com/feeds/user/10826) which right now does not include your latest comment nor your latest edit of this very question yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[rss2email](http://www.allthingsrss.com/rss2email/) is an awesome script for this purpose (it can even parse Atom feeds). It is officially supported on Linux and Windows, but as it is a Python script, it should work on OS X just fine, as Python is installed by default on it.

To check the feeds every minute you can add an entry like this to `crontab`:

```
* * * * * /path/to/r2e run
```

`crontab` can be edited with `crontab -e` on most Unixes; here is an [article](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2001020700163714) about OS X cron variant.

Comment: @Arjan, thanks, edited the answer. I did knew that Ruby is installed by default, but was not sure about Python.